# iOS - NSURLConnection - Proper encoding of characters in request

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

In my iOS application, i'm posting the request to server using NSURLConnection. The following is the code that I'm using:

```
NSString* str = @"http://www.myserver.com/post.php?action=rating&grade=A+&name=vasu";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If you see the grade, its equal to "A+" 
But its posting only "A" as grade to server. Even though when I'm encoding the string appropriately, why is it not able to post the request properly?
Is it something that has to be handled on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + sign is a reserved character for URL encoding (for 'space'). Although the escaped value for + should be %2B after `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, well... it isn't. What you can do though is to add a simple category into `NSString` to bypass this problem. You can find a relevant [blog post here](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) and some information on [URL encoding here](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/)

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes..... But my server is treating "A%2B" as string, instead of treating it as "A+", what should I change on my server side?

Comment: Well I guess you'll just have to decode the string back in whatever language you use on the server

Comment: What is your server-side language?

Comment: Its PHP that is used on server side.

Comment: Then use PHP's `urldecode` function. See the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php